# Convert Base64 image to file path image in iOS programming

Tags: javascript, ios, base64, decode, cordova-plugins

I am using conversion from base64 to a String while I need it as image file path in iOS native plugin

Something like this in android which is converting bitmap to file I need its alternative in iOS

```
 private String convertBitmapToFile(Bitmap photo)
```

As my code conversion for base64 to string is not calling a call back method "**profileBase64Callback**"

```
 plugin call://here citizen.profileImage is in base64 format
 myPlugin.convertToFile("profileBase64Callback", citizen.profileImage,  function(){ }, function(){ });
```

Nativeplugin.m

```
 - (void)convertToFile:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command{
      NSDictionary* options = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
      if ([command.arguments count] > 0) {
          options = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
          NSString *base64Data =[options objectForKey:@"base64"];
          NSLog(@"strttrtr :%@", base64Data);
    }

      NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString: base64Data options:0];
      NSString *strCOnvert = [NSString base64StringFromData:data length:[data length]];//Instead of this string I want decoded format(file path) to send to javascript Or if any other format which fixes my issue


   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:strCOnvert];
    [pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:true];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];      
    NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@);", @"profileBase64Callback", strCOnvert];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

});
```

calling a javascript method to execute:

```
         //Need this imageURI after conversion which I am unable to convert
        function profileBase64Callback(imageURI){
             console.log("profileImage path " );
            //updating to database
             updateCitizenValue("profileImage", imageURI);
             setTimeout(getCitizen(function(citizenVal){

          }), 5000);
 }//this method is not called due to error in conversion.
```

Can anyone please let me know where am I going wrong..trying to decode and Image in base64 format to an actual file

Comment: If I m sending empty data in NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@);", @"profileBase64Callback", @""]; instead of strCOnvert in above code, than my call back method is called as..console==citizenVal.profileImage : undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code solved my issue:

```
- (void)convertToFile:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command{

    NSDictionary* options = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    NSString *base64String;
    if ([command.arguments count] > 0) {
        options = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
        base64String = [options objectForKey:@"base64"];
        methodname1 =[options objectForKey:@"callback"];

    }

    NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:methodname1 options:0];

   NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"]; 
  /*
    identify the home directory and file name
   */
  NSLog(@"----jpgPath--%@",jpgPath);
  [data writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];



   /*
   Send resulting data to cordova plugin
   */
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"OK"];
    [pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:true];

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];

    NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@);", @"profileBase64Callback", jpgPath];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

    });

 }
```